# I need to test django filters applying different lookup_expr on the same field

Tags: django, django-filter, pytest-django, django-filters

I have a challenge model with fields: name, start_date and end_date. I need to apply different django filters to each field like this

```
class ChallengeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Challenge
        fields = {
            "name": ["exact", "icontains"],
            "start_date": ["exact", "lte", "gte"],
            "end_date": ["exact", "lte", "gte"],
        }
```

when I test the exact lookup_expr it works okay but I need help testing "icontains" or "lte" or "gte"

Here's my test for exact

```
def test_challenge_filter_by_name(self, user):
        c1 = ChallengeFactory(name="chal", owner=user)
        c2 = ChallengeFactory(name="star", owner=user)

        data = {
            "name": "chal",
        }
        challenge_filter = ChallengeFilter(data, queryset=Challenge.objects.all())
        assert challenge_filter.is_valid()
        assert challenge_filter.qs.count() == 1
```

and here's the test I tried with contains but if fails assert 0 == 1

```
def test_challenge_filter_by_name_contains(self, user):
        c1 = ChallengeFactory(name="chal", owner=user)
        c2 = ChallengeFactory(name="star", owner=user)

        data = {
            "name": "challenge",
        }
        challenge_filter = ChallengeFilter(data, queryset=Challenge.objects.all())
        assert challenge_filter.is_valid()
        assert challenge_filter.qs.count() == 1
```

I also don't know how to test gte and lte for dates.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if "challenge" is contained in either "chal" or "star". You should name one Challange "challenge" and then filter by "chal".

```
c1 = ChallengeFactory(name="challange", owner=user)
c2 = ChallengeFactory(name="star", owner=user)

data = {
    "name": "chall",
}
challenge_filter = ChallengeFilter(data, queryset=Challenge.objects.all())
assert challenge_filter.is_valid()
assert challenge_filter.qs.count() == 1
```

Comment: The same, it fails